# Which github repos I am watching by default when added to a team in a organization

Tags: git, github

Assume there is a github organization "orgA" and a team within this organization "TeamA". And members of "TeamA" gets committer writes to "RepoA", "RepoB"...."RepoN".

What I observed is, when a user added to "TeamA", where he get priviledge tocommit to all repos I have mentioned, he is only get watched to random set of repos that belongs to this organization.

Can anyone tell me the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 0):

That could be possibly customised by the organiser of the team.

See [this](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/) for more information.